# How to iterate over columns and check condition by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have data for many countries over a period of time (2001-2003). It looks something like this:

| index | year | country | inflation | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | AFG | nan | 48 |
| 2 | 2002 | AFG | nan | 49 |
| 3 | 2003 | AFG | nan | 50 |
| 4 | 2001 | CHI | 3.0 | nan |
| 5 | 2002 | CHI | 5.0 | nan |
| 6 | 2003 | CHI | 7.0 | nan |
| 7 | 2001 | USA | nan | 220 |
| 8 | 2002 | USA | 4.0 | 250 |
| 9 | 2003 | USA | 2.5 | 280 |

I want to drop countries in case there is no data (i.e. values are missing for all years) for any given variable.

In the example table above, I want to drop AFG (because it misses all values for inflation) and CHI (GDP missing). I **don't want** to drop observation #7 just because one year is missing.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: can you give an example of before and expected output?

Comment: Hey, sure. I have edited the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by filtering all values that have nan in one of (inflation, GDP):

```
(
    df.groupby(['country'])
    .filter(lambda x: not x['inflation'].isnull().all() and not x['GDP'].isnull().all())
)
```

Note, if you have more than two columns you can work on a more general version of this:

```
df.groupby(['country']).filter(lambda x: not x.isnull().all().any())
```

If you want this to work with a specific range of year instead of all columns, you can set up a mask and change the code a bit:

```
mask = (df['year'] >= 2002) & (df['year'] <= 2003) # mask of years
grp = df.groupby(['country']).filter(lambda x: not x[mask].isnull().all().any())
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!!

Is it possible to manipulate this for a range of years? If my total range is 1980-2000, and I want to drop if x.isnull() for all in the range (say) 1980-1990.

Comment: @JoaoPedroBastos yes indeed, you will need to create a mask based on the years you need (this could also be any condition you need) and then apply it to `x` in the lambda expression. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
# check where the sum is equal to 0 - means no values in the column for a specific country
group_by = df.groupby(['country']).agg({'inflation':sum, 'GDP':sum}).reset_index()

# extract only countries with information on both columns
indexes = group_by[ (group_by['GDP'] != 0) & ( group_by['inflation'] != 0) ].index
final_countries = list(group_by.loc[ group_by.index.isin(indexes), : ]['country'])

# keep the rows contains the countries

df = df.drop(df[~df.country.isin(final_countries)].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape the data frame from long to wide, drop nulls, and then convert back to wide.

To convert from long to wide, you can use [pivot functions](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/reshape-long-wide-pandas-python-pivot-function/). [See this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe).

Here's code for dropping nulls, after its reshaped:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how= 'any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True) # Delete rows, where any value is null
```

To convert back to long, you can use pd.melt.